# Code Signing JavaFX Executable with VBScript, the SignTool errors with Access Denied

Tags: java, vbscript, javafx, bundle, code-signing

Alright so I've finally figured out how to go about code-signing the executable created by the JavaFX Bundler BEFORE (I hope) it is placed by the INNO script into a setup file : There's just one problem :

[image: ACCESS DENIED]

I've broken myself into pieces trying to resolve this stupid problem but the Access Denied error keeps popping up. This is the VBScript I'm using to try and make this work.

Initially I thought it was a permission error but as I was able to successfully call the script elevated, and still got this error, I can only assume I am mistaken. So...

Can someone please tell me what it is I am doing wrong here?

```
<?xml version = "1.0" ?>
<package>
    <job id="CodeSign">
    <script language = "VBScript">
        <![CDATA[
        WScript.Echo "Setting bElevate to False. . ."
        bElevate = false

        If WScript.Arguments.Count > 0 Then
            WScript.Echo "Arguments.Count > 0"
            If WScript.Arguments(WScript.Arguments.Count-1) <> "|" Then
            WScript.Echo "Arg N - 1 != ""|"" . . ."
            bElevate = true
            End If
        End If

        If bElevate Or WScript.Arguments.Count = 0 Then
            WScript.Echo "Elevating . . ."
            ElevateUAC
        End If

        Dim Shell
        Set Shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        Shell.Run "C:\Sign.bat ""Registration Test\Registration Test.exe""", 1, True
        Set Shell = Nothing

        Sub ElevateUAC
            sParams = "|"

            If WScript.Arguments.Count > 0 Then
            For I = WScript.Arguments.Count - 1 to 0 Step -1
                SParams = " " & WScript.Arugments(I) & sParams
            Next
            End If

            Dim objShell
            Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
            objShell.ShellExecute "wscript.exe", """" & WScript.ScriptFullName & """ """ & sParams & """", "", "runas", 1
            WScript.Echo "Elevated . . ."
            WScript.Quit
        End Sub
        ]]>
    </script>
    </job>
</package>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I found it. This is pretty painful because there's (if I'm using this term in the correct context) "race conditions" here in that if the code signing doesn't finish before you start running the process again, it fails because it can't do anything with the .exe because it's being used by another process.

Turns out as long as your IDE is running in Admin (for Windows anyway) there's no need to elevate your script either.

Anyay, my problem was that the file was being set as Read-Only. VERY annoying but fortunately VBScript allows for you to change a files attributes so it was just a matter of doing that before trying to code-sign it :

```
<?xml version = "1.0" ?>
<package>
    <job id="CodeSign">
    <script language = "VBScript">
        <![CDATA[    
            'Set File as Normal. . .

            Dim objFSO, objFile
            Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
            Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile("<Relative Path>\<File.exe>")
            objFile.Attributes = 0

            Dim Shell
            Set Shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
            Shell.Run "<Code Sign> ""<Relative Path>\<File.exe>""", 1, True
            Set Shell = Nothing
            Set objFSO = Nothing
            Set objFile = Nothing
        ]]>
    </script>
    </job>
</package>
```

So now, finally, at LONG LAST we have a complete and viable answer to this, evidently very esoteric question that no one but myself has dealt with (or is a very closely guarded secret, I'm not sure which) : How do you code-sign the executable created by a JavaFX bundle before it gets stored?

- Create a WSF file with either JavaScript or VBScript (your
  preference)
- Add the directory in which the file is being stored to the Class Path (for NetBeans you go to Tools -> Options -> Java Tab, select Add Directory next to Class Path, browse to the directory, and add it).
- In your WSF file, in the Script section, get the file object and set its attributes to normal (0).
- Then Shell.Run your preferred method of code signing applications. 1 is for showing the Code Sign window, True is to make the VBScript wait until it's finished to hopefully avoid a race condition.

The .exe will ALWAYS be stored one directory up from the WSF script file so the relative path is always going to be `<FILENAME>\<FILENAME.exe>`.

I really, REALLY hope this saves someone a LOT of grief some day...